# Pandas: Merging 2 Dataframes while keeping the the same index of the main df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to merge 2 Dataframes: df and relations_df

**df:** *(df's Index is post's ID)*

Example df:

```
Post     similar_posts
-----     --------
Head-1    [123046, 1915, 111357]
Head-2    [654, 239]
```

Example relations_df:

```
id   related_id   keywords
---   ---------   --------
17    123046      ['key1', 'key2']
17    1915        ['key1', 'key2', 'key6']
17    111357      ['key3', 'key4']
18    654         ['key4', 'key6', 'key1']
18    239         ['key5', 'key2']
```

Expected Output: ***(df's index should persist)***

```
Title     similar_posts           keywords
-----     --------                --------
Head-1    [123046, 1915, 111357]  [['key1', 'key2'], ['key1', 'key2', 'key6'], ['key3', 'key4']]
Head-2    [654, 239]              [['key4', 'key6', 'key1'], ['key5', 'key2']]
```

I am not very knowledgeable with pandas yet, so I tried to ask ChatGPT and failed to get an acceptable answer...

This is my code as of now:

```
def addkeywords(args):
    df, relations_df = args
    
    # Merge relations_df with df on 'id' and 'related_id'
    merged_df = pd.merge(df, relations_df, left_on='id', right_on='related_id', suffixes=('_left', '_right'), how='left')
    
    # Group by 'id' and aggregate 'keywords' into lists
    grouped_df = merged_df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['keywords'].agg(list)
    # grouped_df.rename(columns={'keywords_right': 'keywords'}, inplace=True)
    
    # Merge back to the original DataFrame
    df = pd.merge(df, grouped_df, on='id', how='left')
    
    # Fill NaN values in 'keywords' column with empty lists
    df['keywords'].fillna(value='', inplace=True)
    
    return df
```

The index of 'df' Dataframe should be the same (As the Index represents the post ID in df)

The index of 'relations_df' is autogenerated, so it can change.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Can you provide code of 2 input dataframe? Please provide code that can generate input when dictionary or list exist in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Group by 'id' and aggregate 'related_id' and 'keywords'
df_grouped = relations_df.groupby('id').agg({'related_id': list, 'keywords': list}).reset_index()
df_grouped.set_index('id', inplace=True)
  
# Merge on 'id' of relations_df and 'index' of df
merged_df = pd.merge(df, df_grouped, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I managed to get the desired output using the aboove code.

1. Compressed the flattened relations_df and set its index to 'id'
2. Merged 'df' and 'relations_df' on their indexes

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

One possible way, although there might be better methods, is to aggregate with explode & merge into a list.

```
out = (df
       .explode('similar_posts')
       .merge((relations_df.explode('keywords')
               .rename({'related_id': 'similar_posts'}, axis=1)
               .drop('id', axis=1)
              ), how='left')
       .groupby('similar_posts', as_index=False, sort=False)
       .agg({'Post': 'first', 'keywords': list})
       .groupby('Post', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
      )
```

out

[image]

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Post': ['Head-1', 'Head-2'], 'similar_posts': [[123046, 1915, 111357], [654, 239]]}
data2 = {'id': [17, 17, 17, 18, 18], 'related_id': [123046, 1915, 111357, 654, 239], 'keywords': [['key1', 'key2'], ['key1', 'key2', 'key6'], ['key3', 'key4'], ['key4', 'key6', 'key1'], ['key5', 'key2']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
relations_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Hi Kim, I am sorry for the late reply. I was very busy lately... (And I appreciate the time you took to help me out)
I tried your code, everything worked as expected, except that the index were not carried over from my original df.
I managed to solve this problem on my own after playing around with your solution.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Sniper1999 If this answer was helpful, please mark it as "accepted" to help others who may find this question useful in their search. It is important to indicate that the answer has been accepted.

Comment: I have posted my answer and marked it as accepted, as your solution did not fulfill the condition: where 'df' index should persist.

Although your answer helped me to find my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sniper1999 My response preserves the content of the 'Post' column, not the index. This is because you did not provide your sample in code. If your index is important, you should have provided the sample in code. Alternatively, you can simply add reset_index() in your sample since I have also provided the sample code. Please do not misrepresent my response as an inaccurate one. It is a response that matches my sample, and if you cannot handle a simple reset_index, you should provide the sample in code.

Comment: @Sniper1999 Regardless, simply asking questions and leaving them unanswered is a waste of everyone's time. You should have fixed the minor sample issues with your own involvement, but you abandoned them as well. The problem is that people who ask questions and then leave them unanswered are wasting other people's time. In the future, please avoid wasting the time of others.

Comment: Yeah, you are right I should have provided the samples and the expected output. And should have replied as soon as possible. I will keep this in mind when asking questions.  Thanks for pointing out the issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is not designed to work with nested structures such as list. While possible to achieve this in pure pandas (by exploding, merging, aggregating again), that would not be efficient. The simplest approach remains to use a dictionary and loop over the keys.

```
d = (relations_df
     .set_index('related_id')['keywords']
     .to_dict()
     )

df['keywords'] = [[d.get(x) for x in l]
                  for l in df['similar_posts']]
```

Note that all created sublists are shared with those in the dictionary. If you plan to mutate them you probably should make a copy:

```
df['keywords'] = [[d.get(x).copy() for x in l]
                  for l in df['similar_posts']]
```

Output:

```
     Post           similar_posts                                          keywords
0  Head-1  [123046, 1915, 111357]  [[key1, key2], [key1, key2, key6], [key3, key4]]
1  Head-2              [654, 239]                [[key4, key6, key1], [key5, key2]]
```